# Power Query Invalid Column with parameter

Tags: sql, parameter-passing, powerquery

OK, So I have a Power Query which uses a function to grab a parameter from an Excel Sheet and output a value.  It works fine.  There are three such parameters in this particular Query, all in the WHERE portion.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM AcctHist 
WHERE FiscYr LIKE '2019' 
AND LedgerID LIKE 'Actual' 
AND CpnyID LIKE 'NAH'
```

If I use hard values, the query works fine.  If I use the parameter for the FiscYr column, it works fine.  If I use the parameter for either LedgerID or CpnyID, the query returns an "Invalid Column" error.  Here's what the query looks like in the advanced editor for Power Query:

```
let
Year = Text.From(fnGetParameter("Year")),
Ledger = Text.From(fnGetParameter("Ledger")),
Fund = Text.From(fnGetParameter("Fund")),
Source = Sql.Database(("Server"), ("Database"), [Query="SELECT#(tab)#(lf)#(tab)*#(lf)FROM#(tab)#(lf)#(tab)AcctHist#(lf)WHERE#(tab)#(lf)       FiscYr LIKE '2019' AND#(lf)       LedgerID LIKE 'Actual' AND#(lf)       CpnyID LIKE 'NAH'"])
in
Source
```

As written, this works fine, and gives me the report I need.
Changing the `'2019'` to `"&Year&"` inputs the parameter specified (in this case, 2019) and the query still works fine
Changing either `'Actual'` or `'NAH'` in the exact same fashion gives me the "Invalid Column" error.
Why is it doing this, and what can I do to fix it?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the change from '2019' to "&Year&" is exactly that, the SQL is OK because it is taking the *2019* as a number (because the result is not surrounded by single tics).
If you forget the single tics on the other values, the query engine is going to look for columns named Ledger or Fund.

If this assertion is correct, your 'not working' where clause looks something like this:

```
WHERE FiscYr LIKE " & Year & "
AND LedgerID LIKE " & Ledger & "
AND CpnyID LIKE " & Fund & "
```

but should be

```
WHERE FiscYr LIKE " & Year & "
AND LedgerID LIKE '" & Ledger & "' --note the single tics just inside of the double-quotes
AND CpnyID LIKE '" & Fund & "'
```

Comment: Thnk you SO much!  I knew it was something small like that, but having self-taught myself all of this, I just couldn't get a handle on it.